# Array returning undefined in Vue from indexedDB

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vue-component, javascript-objects, indexeddb

The console.log in my indexedDB works and returns the result that I want; an array of objects that is currently in the store. So my code there is correct. I'm going to use this information to build a table. However, in Vue it returns undefined. I'm trying to set the leagues array in Vue to equal the result array that indexedDB gives, but it returns undefined.

This is the code in Vue:

```
<script>
import * as db from "../db/db.js";

export default {
  name: "leaguesTable",
  data: function() {
    return {
      leagues: []
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    this.leagues = db.getAllInStore("meta", "leagues");
    console.log(this.leagues);
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my indexedDB code:

```
function getAllInStore(dbName, storeName) {
  let db;

  var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);

  request.onerror = function(event) {
    alert("Database error" + event.target.errorCode);
  };

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    let tx = db.transaction(storeName, "readonly");

    tx.onerror = function(event) {
      alert("Transaction error" + event.target.errorCode);
    };

    let store = tx.objectStore(storeName);

    let result = store.getAll();

    tx.oncomplete = function() {
      alert("This should work");
      console.log(result.result);
      return result.result;
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your created hook you need to make sure to return a value from `db.getAllInStore` so that `this.leagues` assumes that value.

Next, In the `getAllInStore` function `result.result` gets returned from the transaction but not within `onComplete` or the enclosing `getAllInStore` function.

Since the db uses event hooks like onError and onComplete, Returning the request won't give you the result of the call to the db. In order to return the value of an async operation in javascript, typically callbacks or promises are used. The example below makes use of promises to solve the issue.

Vue JS:

```
<script>
import * as db from "../db/db.js";

export default {
  name: "leaguesTable",
  data: function() {
    return {
      leagues: []
    };
  },
  // async is necessary to use await
  created: async function() {
    // await is es2016 syntactic sugar for retrieving the value of a promise
    this.leagues = await db.getAllInStore("meta", "leagues");
    console.log(this.leagues);
  }
};
</script>
```

IndexDB:

```
function getAllInStore(dbName, storeName) {
  // resolve param is a function that signifies a successful operation
  // reject param is a function that should be called whenever a check or error occurs
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let db;
    let request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);
      request.onerror = (event) => reject(event);
      request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        db = event.target.result;

        let tx = db.transaction(storeName, "readonly");
        request.onerror = (event) => reject(event);

        let store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
        let result = store.getAll();
        tx.oncomplete = (result) => resolve(result.result);
      };
  });
}
```

Further Reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Comment: @Ikroneman Thank you. This worked. The only thing I had to change was tx.oncomplete = () => resolve(result.result); When I put result in the parenthesis eslint gave me a no-unused-var error. removing it fixed it and now it returns what I want. Thanks a bunch